# Google Maps API: Premier License or excess map loads?

Tags: google-maps

I am currently looking for a way on how to deal with the Google Maps API usage limits. I am planning a redesign of our page that will probably get around 2 million map loads per month.

This will surely break the usage limit of 750000 map loads per month  available in the free version. If we pay for excess map loads, this  means we would have to pay 5000$ per month. The other option would be to use a Premier license, however there is very few information 
available on the usage limits for this and the price. I have filled the request form to get a custom offer from Google, but I did not get any response yet.

Can anyone of the Premier license holders tell me which option will be cheaper for my usage pattern, paying for Premier license or paying for excess map loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the Maps Product Manager](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-definitive-answer-to-the-number-of-page-loads-on-Google-Maps-API-Premier-license), the actual pricing you'll see depends on several factors and works on a sliding scale. [The Register says](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/10/27/google_maps_api_no_longer_free/) that Premier licenses start at $10,000/year. I've also seen that number cited several other places. So, while waiting for a real response you can start your deliberations from there, I guess. But it's going to be of relatively limited *practical* use.

Comment: Thanks, good link on Quora! I will wait for a final answer from the Google Maps team.